# $(this) reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('td').click(function(){    
    $('input:radio').click(function(){    
    })
})
```

If I use $(this) after second line it will refer to the radio button. How to refer to the td element from that line? I am trying to add an id to td element but it adds this to the radio button.

Comment: this is wrong way to register a click

Comment: It's called closures, variables declared in $('td').click function are available in $('input:radio').click function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures If you need JQuery object in the $('input:radio').click function it's better to set self to $(this) then you don't have to convert the td to a jquery object multiple times. So you set self like so: $self=$(this) The $ for $self is not needed but it's good practice to store JQuery variables in names starting with $.

Comment: I think this question is clear, even if what the code is doing is odd. I don't see that as a valid reason to down vote it.

Comment: @HMR - You gave a good quick definition of a closure and made a couple other good points. You should have put your comment in an answer. I would have up voted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

As others have shown, you can use a closure:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var td = this; // Creates a closure
    $('input:radio').click(function(event) {
        // this and event.target refer to the radio button
        // td refers to the <td> element
    });
});
```

Or you can use `$.prox()`:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    $('input:radio').click($.proxy(function(event) {
        // this refers to the td
        // event.target refers to the radio button
    }, this));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Save a reference to this before the radio button handler:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var self = this;
    $('input:radio').click(function () {
        // self refers to 'this' from the td selection here
    });
});
```

I'm not sure this is what you really want to do, however, as what you're doing is assigning a click handler for a click on a radio button on a click on the td. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').click(function(){    
    var tdElement = $(this);
    $('input:radio').click(function(){    
        // Do whatever you like with tdElement here
    })
})
```